# Bash loading function from external source produces command not found

Tags: bash

I've looked at many resources on here and I can't seem to find a solution that works for me. More than likely it's my config that's wrong.

All the scripts are in the same directory. For the sake of simplicity I will simplify it to two `.sh` files and use simple use cases.

**script1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source script2.sh
X=$(trim_quote "\"hello\"")

echo $X
```

**script2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

trim_quotes () {
    echo $1 | sed 's/"//g'
}
```

If I do the following `./script1.sh` I get the following output:

```
trim_quote: command not found
```

If I test the function from within `script2.sh` it works fine, but for some reason it doesn't agree with being referenced externally.

I have tried:

```
source ./script2.sh

PWD=$(pwd)
source $PWD/script2.sh

. script2.sh

. ./script2.sh

PWD=$(pwd)
. $PWD/script2.sh

$include script2.sh

$include ./script2.sh

PWD=$(pwd)
$include $PWD/script2.sh
```

all of which produce the same error.

Comment: trim_quotes != trim_quote ?

Comment: @TimD Correct. Overlooked the simplest thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo. trim_quoteS is the correct name of function.

```
#!/bin/bash

source script2.sh
X=$(trim_quotes "\"hello\"")

echo $X
```

Run:

```
$ ./script1.sh 
hello
```